# Typeface.createFromAsset Crashes Custom textView

Tags: android, textview, android-typeface, roboto

I want to implement Roboto font to my app, so following guides on stackoverflow I created 2 new views, one for AutoCompleteTextView and one for the regular TextView

when using a layout with the AutoCompleteTextView that I created everything works fine, and if I add my TextView without a font it also works, but if I specify a font to the TextView my app throws the following Execption:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class layouttesting.busalarmclock.com.busalarmclocktesting.Views.TypeFaceTextView
```

I did some digging and understood that the line

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
```

was crashing my app, even though I use the same exact code in my other view and it works great..

full TextView:

```
public TypeFaceTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TypeFaceTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //Typeface.createFromAsset doesn't work in the layout editor. Skipping...
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        return;
    }

    TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TypeFaceTextView);
    String fontName = styledAttrs.getString(R.styleable.TypeFaceTextView_typeface);
    styledAttrs.recycle();

    if (fontName != null) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}


public TypeFaceTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

Full AutoCompleteTextView code:

```
public TypeFaceAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TypeFaceAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if(isInEditMode())
    {
        return;
    }

    TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TypeFaceAutoCompleteTextView);
    String fontName = styledAttributes.getString(R.styleable.TypeFaceAutoCompleteTextView_autocomplete_typeface);
    styledAttributes.recycle();

    if(fontName != null)
    {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
        setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}

public TypeFaceAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that it only happens when I put a normal TextView before it...

adding full crash report - note that there is no Caused By..

```
06-16 22:12:52.876 21453-21453/layouttesting.busalarmclock.com.busalarmclocktesting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                  Process: layouttesting.busalarmclock.com.busalarmclocktesting, PID: 21453
                                                                                                  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.thoughtlesskyle.theme.roam2, iconPack:com.thoughtlesskyle.theme.roam2, fontPkg:com.thoughtlesskyle.theme.roam2, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.thoughtlesskyle.theme.roam2, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.thoughtlesskyle.theme.roam2}
                                                                                                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class layouttesting.busalarmclock.com.busalarmclocktesting.Views.TypeFaceTextView
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                                      at layouttesting.busalarmclock.com.busalarmclocktesting.Fragments.SearchLineFragment.onCreateView(SearchLineFragment.java:22)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1632)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1235)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1083)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1609)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:669)
                                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:736)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1458)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:746)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2899)
                                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18799)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2108)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1224)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
                                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
                                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                                    at and
```

**EDIT EDIT**
It worked once after it did a cold swap because it changed the rez IDs
Now it doesnt work again..

**EDIT EDIT EDIT**
When I do Clean and Rerun it works just fine, I suppose this is a bug with instant run?

Comment: Please post the entire Java stack trace, including any `Caused by` stanzas.

Comment: added, though there is no caused by stanza..

Comment: I feel very confident that there is more to the stack trace than this, including one or more `Caused by` sections, showing the actual underlying exception.

Comment: It does seem to be cut in the middle of a word, but that's all the logcat is showing me. Do you know of a way to show the missing message? And it seems that when I restart Android Studio it works just fine, only when I do some changes and Instant run works it crahes. Could it be that instant run is doing something bad?

Comment: If you create a new typeface in every single text view instance, your application is going to lag like a bitch when you scroll something more complicated. Been there, fixed that.

Comment: what do you suggest doing?